# How to use MFC classes in a Qt application?

Tags: c++, qt, mfc

I'm developing a big application in Qt. There are some classes/components that do not offer the performance I need, so I want to use a native solution.

I installed Visual Studio 2010 with MFC, and I actually know the location of the library with open source.

How can I link my Qt app to MFC and use some of its classes?

Comment: Are you using VS 2010 for your Qt development? (And do you have any particular reason to believe that MFC controls [which are themselves wrappers around Win32 controls] are any more performant than the Qt controls?)

Comment: I'm using Qt Creator. And yes, I spent several weeks doing research and I am 100% sure that I need native solution here. It's a problem with fetching shell icons. Qt converts them via QPixmap which is not thread safe and causes UI freeze (~200 milliseconds for every icon). `(HIMAGELIST) SHGetFileInfo` is at least 5 times faster.

Comment: Wouldn't the native solution to be to use the WinAPI directly?  Including all of MFC just for this is like using a sledge hammer to crack a nut.  Why not code a wrapper around the Win API that you need access to, that is all MFC does?

Comment: @Stefan, you are right. It's just that MFC has this function that does all I need. I'll have to rewrite it in pure WIN API.

Comment: Yeah I see your point. However it sounds like integrating mfc into your app is non trivial anyway and also carries a massive overhead. If the win Api function is a pain to wrap why. It post on here for some advice?